# hook_node_presave () showing error

Tags: taxonomy-terms, hooks, nodes

When I am inserting a new article there is an error -

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_tags in
>   hook_node_presave() (line 344 of
>   D:\wamp\www...)

The code for line 344 is-

```
function mltag_node_presave($node) {
...
$count = count($node->field_tags[$node->language]); //line 344
..
}
```

This error only shows up when **adding** a new article, and **not** when **editing** an article.
The line 344 is just to count the number of term-ids in the textfield for tags.
Any suggestions ??

EDIT - field_tags is the name of the default Tag textfield added in the add-article page

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do an isset($node->field_tags[$node->language]), if it is empty $node->field_tags[$node->language] will not exist. Could you check if it is only articles with the empty field_tags that are affected?